# Android: how to reduce TabLayout internal padding

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I'm using a TabLyout but there is too much distance between the text and the line below the text.
[image]

Of course I already tried to play around with padding but with no luck, is there any way to reduce this internal padding?

Here my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    app:tabPadding="0dp"
                    app:tabGravity="center"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="#ddffffff"
                    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
                    app:tabTextColor="#ffffff" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Use the following attributes to reduce the padding between the tabs.

```
app:tabPaddingEnd="2dp"
app:tabPaddingStart="2dp"
```

By default, I think those values are around 12dp.

**app:tabPaddingEnd** - The preferred padding along the end edge of tabs.

**app:tabPaddingStart** - The preferred padding along the start edge of tabs.

Answer (score 5):

In order to reduce a distance between the text and the line below the text you can use `android:layout_height="size_in_dp"`. For example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"                        
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="#ddffffff"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
                    app:tabTextColor="#ffffff" />
```